# JS: How do I use an element in an array and then get rid of it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a matching card game and trying to 'shuffle' my cards. Here is how I have everything set up right now:

Cards' data are objects

```
var idea = {
    id: 1,
    english: 'idea',
    pinyin: 'zhǔyì',
    hanyu: '主意'
}
```

The "deck" is an array with all the cards.

```
var vocabArray = [idea, getOn, need, getOff, beautiful, scenery, sameAlike, because, help, play];
```

This is how the cards are getting into my HTML.

```
var cardIndexNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var cardReturn = vocabArray[cardIndexNum];
document.getElementById('card1').innerHTML = '<h2>' + cardReturn.hanyu + '<br>' + cardReturn.pinyin + '</h2>';
```

HTML

```
div class='card' id='card1'>
    JAVASCRIPT PUTS CARD INFO AND H TAGS HERE
</div>
```

Right now I some cards are appearing more than once because after I use the card it is still in the array. I tried using .splice on the cards after they were used, but then I would sometimes get an array element with undefined attributes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements `delete`.

Comment: Shuffle the deck, `pop()` them (or `shift()` them) off the array as needed.

Comment: You should do `var cardIndexNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * vocabArray);`, so you're selecting from among the cards available after you splice used cards from `vocabArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a **array of objects**, you can't use splice directly over the array inorder to remove the element.

*(this example uses **jQuery**)*

```
var findAndRemove = function(array,  property, value) {
    $.each(array, function(index, result) {
          if(result[property] == value) {
              array.splice(index, 1);
          }
    }
}
```

You need to pass `vocabArray` and `id` and `value` as function parameter

```
findAndRemove(vocabArray, "id", 1);
```

**EDIT**

To support normal javascript

*(NOT TESTED)*

```
var findAndRemove = function(array, value) {
    for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if(array[i].id == value) {
              array.splice(i, 1);
          }
    }
}
```

Call by

```
findAndRemove(vocabArray, 1);
```

Comment: I'm trying to write this with plain Javascript. Could I do the following? 1) Choose element from array. 2) After I use the element, change its position to the be the last element of the array. 3) Subtract one from my random number generator.  If so, I just need to know how to do step 2.

Comment: @Josh The edit supports only id, please make sure to give a suitable name to the function.

Comment: I don't think that `$.each` likes it when you `splice` an item during the iteration…

Comment: @Chandresh . Thanks for all your help. I"m pretty new to JS and didn't rally understand how your answer worked. Here's what I did that ended up working. 1.) Gave each object a property called "used" and set it to false. 2.) Once a card had been used the 'used' property was set to true. 3.) Created an If statement that would only let me pick unused cards from my deck. If card.used == true, it would re-pick. After all cards were placed the function reset all properties back to false, otherwise pressing the button again would start an infinite loop. Thanks, again!